# jQuery/datepicker: set maximum date in terms of years

Tags: jquery, datepicker

In my form I would like the datepicker, initialized to today date, to be settable up to ten years from today. This is what I have tried looking in stackoverflow:

```
jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    yearRange: "-80:+0",
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    maxDate: "+10y"
});

jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

or

```
jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    yearRange: "-80:+0",
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});

var todayDate = new Date();
jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker().datepicker("setDate", todayDate);
jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker().datepicker( "option", "maxDate", new Date(todayDate.getFullYear()+10, todayDate.getMonth(), todayDate.getDate()));
```

and obviously both haven't worked. I think I'm making a stupid mistake caused my lack of experience in jQuery. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this

```
yearRange: "-80:+0",
```

to

```
yearRange: "-80:+10",
```